# How to send post data in start_urls of the scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to crawl a website which supports only post data. I want to send the query params
in post data in all the requests. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

POST requests can be made using scrapy's [Request](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) or [FormRequest](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.FormRequest) classes.

Also, consider using [`start_requests()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.start_requests) method instead of `start_urls` property.

Example:

```
from scrapy.http import FormRequest

class myspiderSpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.example.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        return [ FormRequest("http://www.example.com/login",
                     formdata={'someparam': 'foo', 'otherparam': 'bar'},
                     callback=self.parse) ]
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: But which parameter of `Request` or `FormRequest` should I past the post data to? `body` or `formdata`?

Comment: You should use the `formdata` dict for the post data.

Comment: How do you do it with a list of urls?